# What does underbar y in distribution notation mean?

Tags: statistics, notation, distribution-theory

I was wondering what $\underline y$ means in a distribution notation like this: "The distribution cost y is distributed on $[\underline y, \bar y]$". I know that $\bar y$ could mean the mean of a sample, but I was wondering if anyone please can explain what $\underline y$ here means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s just the name for the two endpoints of the interval from which $y$ is sampled. So $\overline y$ is the upper bound and $\underline y$ is the lower bound. ($\overline y$ denotes the mean in other situations but here it doesn’t.)